# Is there a way autocomplete would work in atom like it does in chrome's/firefox's console?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, atom-editor

I am new to web development, and I find myself often writing javascript code in a separate file. For eg: I have an index.html and the corresponding javascript is in index.js. I start typing `document.addEven...` and I would like the autocomplete to provide me suggestions as it does in chrome's or firefox's console. Or, when I do `document.querySelector('h1').`, it should show me all the properties that I can use(like `onclick` or `innerHTML`). All of this I get in chrome's or firefox's consoles but I miss these things when I am writing javascript. Is there a way I can do this in atom? I guess I am asking what are some nice addons while doing webdev on atom ( or should I be even using atom?).

Comment: You can use `vscode editor` it's free and easy to use :) Or if you are a `atom` fan then i think there may be some packages for that. You can check this one https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-javascript

Comment: Yeah, like @Sifat said, install an autocomplete extension.

Comment: Can you suggest a good autocomplete extension for atom?

Comment: @Sifat Haque Unfortunately, that package doesn't work at all.